# Какой подход лучше: использование js-фреймворка в шаблонах на бэкенде либо отдельно от бэкенда?

Tags: django, веб-программирование

Какой подход лучше: использование js-фреймворка в шаблонах на бэкенде (Django templates) либо отдельно от бэкенда (без шаблонов)?

Comment: зависит от проекта, задач, бюджета, команды (и возможно чего-то еще)...

Comment: так же не стоит забывать про то для кого лучше: для проекта? для вас? для клиента? для владельца студии?..

Comment: на данный вопрос невозможно ответить объективно от слова совсем.